# How to deserialize query string to pojo in cxf java

Tags: java, cxf, deserialization, query-string

I am trying to convert querystring into Pojo. Is there any way to convert query string into pojo. Below is what I have tried so far:

**Request:**

```
POST /Service/services/handler/qpStringtoPOJO HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Cache-Control: no-cache

id=123434&value=BB$@##@FDBB$#Gw3r3232rvd
```

**Pojo:**

```
    package com.nexsols.license.model;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement
    public class Pojo {
        String id;
        String value;
        @XmlElement(name="id")
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @XmlElement(name="value")
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Pojo [id=" + id + ", value=" + value + "]";
        }
    }
```

**Service method:**

```
@POST
@Path("/qpStringtoPOJO")
public String qpStringtoPOJO(@QueryParam("") Pojo pojo){

    System.out.println(pojo);
    return "SUCCESS";
}
```

Currently output is 
Pojo [id=null, value=null]

I am using cxf for my service.Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you can use a map and obtain it from request.getParameterMap().
And then you can pass the required keys to this map to obtain their values.

Answer (score 0):

Given the constraints you have stated in the comments below, here is how I would solve this:

1. Use the @Context annotation to get the HTTP request object
2. Extract the parameters of interest from the request object
3. Construct the POJO yourself

Try this...

```
@POST
@Path("/qpStringtoPOJO")
public String qpStringtoPOJO(@Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest){      
   String id = request.getParameter("id");
   String value = request.getParameter("value");
   Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
   pojo.setId(id):
   pojo.setValue(value);
}
```

Or this (although I have not tested this):

```
@POST
@Path("/qpStringtoPOJO")
public String qpStringtoPOJO(@FormParam("id") String id, @FormParam("value") String value){     
   Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
   pojo.setId(id):
   pojo.setValue(value);
}
```

Comment: After removing that i am getting this error   Nov 16, 2014 11:27:13 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils readFromMessageBody
WARNING: No message body reader has been found for request class Pojo, ContentType : text/plain;charset=UTF-8.
Nov 16, 2014 11:27:13 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
WARNING: WebApplicationException has been caught : no cause is available

Comment: I see the problem.  You need to have the XML representation in the post body.  I will update the answer.

Comment: Ok I can't do that because some third party is sending me this request and they send query string in post body,I have to convert it to Pojo.

Comment: OK, I have a solution that will require just a couple lines of code.  Give me a minute and I will post it.

Comment: Solution posted but for some reason, S.O. code formatting feature is not working for me.  Ugh.  For now, you should be able to copy the text.  I will continue trying to fix the formatting.  Very frustrating.

Comment: NP,this is what I was looking for only thing that is remaining is to make it more generic. Is there some way that I can pick parameter name from pojo xml annotation and the iterate over list of field annotation and then create object.

Comment: I just found this:  Use the JAX-RS @FormParam